# grails duplicate QuartzConfig

Tags: java, grails, weceem

I use quartz in my grails project.

I now wanted to include the weceem plugin (that is a "lightweight" CMS)

It turns out that the plugin itself uses quatz as well.
Now I have a compile error saying:

```
Invalid duplicate class definition of class QuartzConfig : 
The sources xxx\target\work\plugins\weceem-1.4\grails-app\conf\QuartzConfig.groovy and xxx\grails-app\conf\QuartzConfig.groovy each contain a class with the name QuartzConfig. 
QuartzConfig.groovy /xxx/.link_to_grails_plugins/weceem-1.4/grails-app/conf
```

What can I do?

**EDIT:** Of cause, I want to use my QuartzConfig. It should override the plugin one

Comment: could you refactor and rename on of them?

Comment: I looks like quartz is looking for a file that is named like "QuartzConfig". So I can not reame my file because that is the file that I want to use. As the weceem plugin is a plugin I can not refactor this because the soruces are automaticly loaded by maven